# GUI for computer algebra system

Tags: java, scripting, groovy, ide, computer-algebra-systems

Good day. We are working on the framework for computer algebra on Java. At this point it can be used only programmatically (eg. you need to write some code on java or groovy to use it), but it is not so user friendly. It is too complicated to set up a whole development environment and to use Java syntax just to solve some simple problem.

We are now looking for some relatively simple way to create a user interface and syntax for it. Our idea is to use some existing Java-compatible language with simple and powerful syntax (we are thinking about groovy) to write a binding to our library that will hide underlying complex infrastructure with some more natural syntax.

For example:

Java:

```
Tensor t1 = Tensors.parse(“T_mn”);
Tensor t2 = Tensors.parse(“2*T_mn”);
Tensor sum = Tensors.sum(t1,t2);
System.out.println(sum.toString(ToStringMode.LaTeX));
```

Groovy:

```
def t1 = parse ‘T_mn’
def t2 = parse ‘2*T_mn’
def sum = t1+t2
latexOut(sum)
```

We need a language with a good IDE (with auto-completion at least), which can be adapted (embeded) for our needs.

What can you recommend for this task ( IDE-Language combination )?

Comment: Is your Eclipse IDE not enough? Has a lot of plugins for alotof languages.

Comment: This kind of open-ended question is one of the categories defined in the FAQ as "off topic". Part of the problem is that there many different answers are equally valid - everyone's experience is different. For example, I loathe Eclipse - the look and feel just doesn't work for me and so I use IDEA by JetBrains. Others have the exact opposite experience.

Comment: I also loathe Eclipse), but in this case I think it is the case, because it is more "embeddable"... Xtext and Xtent (suggested by  Konstantin Komissarchik) that are powerful tools to solve this problem are based namely on Eclipse. And this is not "off topic" because I get exact answer, and other people that are looking for the same tools will find them quicker. P.S. I also use IDEA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) (a framework for building source editors in Eclipse) and [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) (a simple language that you can use as-is or extend for you own needs).

Comment: @Konstantin Can Xtext create XML output? I have a GEF editor that is based on EMF model and was looking for a way to create text based editor that would allow me to create the EMF model. For example, take Person library. If I said something like define Person bob, my XML would get generated with <person name="bob"/>. Is this something that is possible with Xtext?

Comment: @akravets, Xtext takes care of source language in editor to EMF model. What you do with with an EMF model after that is a distinct problem. You may want to ask a separate question about that.